# Draw an image from URL?

Tags: java, image, draw

it's the first time I'm doing this in Java and am not sure how it works. Is the url supposed to  be a String or a file?

It doesn't work. It gives "change type of ghost to ImageIcon" and i dont want that.

```
String url = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_y3qWcWEV3Gc/TL-Ubk3mx0I/AAAAAAAAAJ0/UxcN2eXwCa4/s200/nes_ms_pac_man_ghost-copy.jpeg";
    Image ghost = new ImageIcon(url);


    g2d.drawImage(ghost, x, y, (ImageObserver) this);
```

Comment: Use an `ImageIcon` and then it's  `getImage()` mehtod: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage()

Comment: @madth3: Check my answer, there's no need to use an ImageIcon at all even if also by using your method it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily load an `ImageIcon` from an URL but you have to use the right constructor:

```
URL url = new URL("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_y3qWcWEV3Gc/TL-Ubk3mx0I/AAAAAAAAAJ0/UxcN2eXwCa4/s200/nes_ms_pac_man_ghost-copy.jpeg");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

To load an `Image` (which is the one you want to use on  a Graphics2D object), while the `ImageIcon` is used in UI components, you should use [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class which gives the functionality:

```
static BufferedImage read(URL input)
```

Actually you could use `ImageIcon.getImage()` but this makes no sense since you don't need an ImageIcon at all. Just use `ImageIO` class.

Comment: That's the same constructor the OP is using and he explicitly says he does not want an `ImageIcon`.

Comment: @madth3: That's not the same constructor. Mine is passing an URL, not a String (which is implicitly interpreted as a filename, and not a remote resource).

Comment: thanks but it still gives me the error change type of ghost to ImageIcon. And then this modifies drawImage to drawLine